# Regex Underscore between numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
<?php
    $string = '395095427174400_558374047513203';
    if(preg_match("/^[0-9][_][0-9]$/",$string)){
        echo "True";
    }else{
        echo "False";
    }
?>
```

Why does my regex not match and underscore between numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `quantifier` to match more number of `digits` before an `underscore`. And you don't really need to have your `underscore` in a `character class`.

You can try this regex: -

```
/^[0-9]+_[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `regex` does match an underscore between numbers, just single digit numbers that is.

`/^[0-9][_][0-9]$/`

```
^      # Start of line
[0-9]  # A single digit
[_]    # An underscore 
[0-9]  # A single digit 
$      # End of line
```

You want to use `+` to match one or more digits:

`/^[0-9]+_[0-9]+$/`

```
^       # Start of line
[0-9]+  # One or more digit
_       # An underscore 
[0-9]+  # One or more digit 
$       # End of line
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `^` and `$` restricts the regex engine to match the whole string and you have more than one digits around `_` so your pattern fails. Adding a `+` with `[0-9]` will solve this issue as other expert(s) suggested like this:

```
/^[0-9]+_[0-9]+$/
```

Also, i would not recommend to use character classes when working with digits, regex engine supports `\d` for this purpose.

Simplify your pattern like this:

```
/^\d+_\d+$/
```

Also, if you are pretty sure that an underscore can only occur in between digit(s) (not start and end), you can even more simplify it like this:

```
/^_|\d+$/
```